# How do I make sense of/manage lwjgl GL* namespaces in Clojure?

Tags: opengl, clojure, lwjgl

This may be a totally noob question, but I've been experimenting with openGL in clojure via LWJGL, and while there are plenty of resources for learning both graphics programming and LWJGL, I've found it frustrating to port them to clojure. All of the different static methods representing openGL calls are associated with different java classes (ie. GL11, GL15, etc.), which presents no real problem in java as they can all be imported via something like "import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*". So I was wondering if there's a way to do the same in clojure (like the way "use" does for clojure namespaces)? And if not, is there an easier way to figure out which class a given method is associated with than stopping to search through the api for each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality you describe is not included in `clojure.core`. It was included in the, now deprecated, `clojure-contrib` project, but including that as a dependency to your project may cause unintended dependency conflicts.

The code for the `import-static` macro is located in the old `clojure-contrib` github repository.

https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/import_static.clj

You should be able to include the single macro in your project without issue.